# How do I receiving job notifications by email?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I have MS SQL Server 2008 R2. I also have database mail configured to my mail server with a email user and password. I have created an operator for this email and assigned that operator to a job with notifications activated to email on job success, complete and failure. But, no email notifications are being sent on any job state.

That said, I have used the test utility to test database mail. These are put into a queue which is building up, but the email is successfully being sent and I receive said email to destination addressed specified in the test. However, again, although the test is working, the queue is still building on each test and job notifications are not working at all.

Upon investigating the sysmail_log and the sysmail_mailitems, I see my test emails succeeding in the sysmail_log and the context of those mails in the sysmail_mailitems. When I run a job, I do not see any indication that database mail is attempting to send or failing in either log.

Lastly, I ran a query to send email using the following SQL (personal information removed):

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='MyProfileName',
@recipients='test@Example.com',
@subject='Test message',
@body='This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'
```

And this query runs and successfully sends an email. So, what gives? Why am I not receiving notifications of emails on jobs when they are set to send the operator an email on success, completion or failure? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please provide the error description. 
USE msdb
go
SELECT items.subject, items.last_mod_date, l.description 
FROM dbo.sysmail_faileditems as items
INNER JOIN dbo.sysmail_event_log AS l ON items.mailitem_id = l.mailitem_id

Comment: As I said, there are no mail errors when a job completes or succeeds. There are also no mail logs either, but the job is set to an operator (Myself) with an email notification attached to that operator as well on the job itself to email this operator when success, completed or failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the job to email you when complete?

Right click the job, select properties, notifications.  Three options to choose when to email the operator: failure, success or complete.  This assumes you did check the mail option.

This article should help!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billramo/archive/2009/03/30/sql-server-agent-and-database-mail-better-together.aspx

**OTHER THINGS TO LOOK AT:**

1 - Did you look at the db mail, sql agent, and sql server logs?  Are there any errors?

2 - Look at the job history.  Does it ever execute the first step?

3 - You can always run the following command as a one line job.

```
select 1 as flag into msdb.dbo.test_job
```

See if the table gets created.  If so, the job is running that step, otherwise it is not.

4 - Look at the database mail system views in msdb for emails.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188023.aspx

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems 
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailattachments 
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log 
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems 
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems
```

5 - Look at the database mail account tables.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount
```

Are you sure there is a default public profile that can be used by all accounts to send mail?

6 - See my step by step article on setting up db mail using TSQL.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1025

It is very difficult to debug such an error remotely w/o access to the system.

I hope these suggestions help!

Comment: Yes, I set the job to an operator (myself) to be emailed when it completes. The operator email is also the same email setup for the database email. It's also the same one used for the SQL test process that succeeded and the SQL code used that also succeeded. It's almost like the job is not assigned a operator to email, but yet it is...

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the steps and report back. I can tell you right for now that database mail on the server has been setup. That's what I did the tests with. Email is coming through and no errors are occurring in the logs. The only problem is when you attach a operator to a job who is setup under the database mail (that is working based on the tests), the job is not triggering the email. It's also not showing any errors in the log or showing a record of the mail even being sent. It's almost like the job notification does not exist, but yet it does.

Comment: I should also mention that when I do the test mail using the test email process during the database mail setup, it shows the email succeeding in the logs. It does not show the same when a job is completed that has an email notification. As well no errors.

Comment: 1) Yes, there are errors during the test mail process. This was because I set the wrong email password. These errors have been resolved and not part of this problem. 2) Yes, the job I assigned the notification too is showing it succeeded through each step. Notification column of history is blank (no notifications sent). 3) Used another job and it executes all steps. 4) I checked these. No logs of the job sending email or failing to send email. 5) I see 3 results. My operator, the email profile and the profileaccount linking my account id to the sysmail profile id. Looks linked.

Comment: Everything looks right. I even used one of your guides to manually create a operator with a email via SQL. It created the operator and assigned the email I specified to that operator. Then I assigned the new operator to the job. When I executed the job, no email either! This is weird. I can send email using the test process. I can even email using SQL code in a procedure. I cannot email off a job notification? wth. :D

Comment: I swear to all that is holy. I hate evil empire so much. It just needed to have the SQL Agent restarted. I swear, this notification setup has been set through multiple SQL server restarts and nothing. Sigh... Thanks for the help Crafty DBA.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  If so, you need to start to rule out things systematically.  POSITIVE TESTS:  1 - Can you right click database mail and send a test message?  Use the default public profile.  2 - Can you execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail from a query window?  If you get these emails, that is good since mail is working ...  I will wait for your feed back.

Comment: Nope, all is fixed. Sorry for late response. :)